# Python playsound module "The driver cannot recognize the specified command parameter."

Tags: python, windows, audio, subdirectory, playsound

Heres the code I'm running:

```
from playsound import playsound
import threading
threading.Thread(target=playsound, args=('Assets\Loss.mp3',)).start()
```

When I run this it gives me this error

```
    Error 259 for command:
        play "Assets\Loss.mp3" wait
    The driver cannot recognize the specified command parameter.

    Error 305 for command:
        close "Assets\Loss.mp3"
    Cannot specify extra characters after a string enclosed in quotation marks.
Failed to close the file: "Assets\Loss.mp3"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ekila\Downloads\Smart Auto Bet\Test.py", line 10, in <module>
    playsound('Assets\Loss.mp3')
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 73, in _playsoundWin
    winCommand(u'play {}{}'.format(sound, ' wait' if block else ''))
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 64, in winCommand
    raise PlaysoundException(exceptionMessage)
playsound.PlaysoundException: 
    Error 259 for command:
        play "Assets\Loss.mp3" wait
    The driver cannot recognize the specified command parameter.
```

What's a little bit more interested is that when I move the mp3 to the same folder and run

```py
from playsound import playsound
import threading
threading.Thread(target=playsound, args=('Loss.mp3',)).start()
```

It plays perfectly fine with no errors but I want to have the mp3 stored in the subdirectory

- I have playsound version 1.2.2 installed.
- I've tried running it without threading

Comment: Use the full path?

Comment: Already tried that but I get a different error